# Linking model with an external socketdll library in modelica

Tags: c++, c, modelica

I am new to modelica and I am trying to link my model to an external socketdll but I can't figure out what causes the error. Is it the incorrect file path indicated in the function? Thanks

```
function constructor
      input String ip = "127.0.0.1";
      output MySocket SocketClient;
    external "C" SocketClient = SocketInitConnect(ip)annotation (Include = "#include \"SocketDll.h\"", 
      IncludeDirectory = "modelica://exfuncExample/Resources/include", 
      Library = "SocketDll", 
      LibraryDirectory = "modelica://exfuncExample/Resources/libs");
    end constructor;

Creating library C:\Users\rss0309\Documents\MWorks\Simulation\Machiningcenter.HIL-7\MWSolver.lib and object C:\Users\rss0309\Documents\MWorks\Simulation\Machiningcenter.HIL-7\MWSolver.exp
momodel_func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SocketClose referenced in function exfuncExamplea_SocketModelsa_testSocketDlla_MySocketa_constructor
momodel_func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SocketInitConnect referenced in function exfuncExamplea_SocketModelsa_testSocketDlla_MySocketa_constructor
momodel_func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Parse referenced in function exfuncExamplea_SocketModelsa_testSocketDlla_Findx
momodel_func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SocketReceive referenced in function exfuncExamplea_SocketModelsa_testSocketDlla_rcv
momodel_func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Compact referenced in function exfuncExamplea_SocketModelsa_testSocketDlla_DataCompact
momodel_func.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SocketSend referenced in function exfuncExamplea_SocketModelsa_testSocketDlla_Send
C:\Users\rss0309\Documents\MWorks\Simulation\Machiningcenter.HIL-7\MWSolver.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals

Linking the model (vc) failed.
```

Comment: Add `Ws2_32.lib` to the linker additional libraries flags